# iOS framework resources, how to have user project automatically include the resource in the build?

Tags: ios, frameworks, resources

So, let's say we have a user / custom framework called mystuff.framework.  In the framework is a resource mydata.plist.

What is the accepted way (if any) that this plist can be included in the using program's main bundle with having to copy / set in the copy resources build phase?

The main reason for this is the user framework is relative to the project and if one copies / moves the plist file to the copy bundle resources it looks like it is a non-relative link?